# Using \color in varwidth environment produces warning and does not work as intended

Tags: errors, warnings, varwidth

Trying to use color in a `varwidth` environment, I stumbled upon
a warning from the `varwidth` package. Inspecting the issue and
trying the same with `\parbox` and the `minipage` environment lead
to the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{varwidth}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
\verb|\parbox| & \verb|\minipage| & \verb|\varwidth| \\

%without color, everything works as expected.
\parbox[t]{4em}{
%  \color{red}
  test
}abc &
\begin{minipage}[t]{4em}
%  \color{red}
  test
\end{minipage}
abc &
\begin{varwidth}[t]{4em}
%  \color{red}
  test
\end{varwidth}
abc\\

% but using \color needs \leavevmode and breaks varwidth
\parbox[t]{4em}{
  \leavevmode
  \color{red}
  test
}abc &
\begin{minipage}[t]{4em}
  \leavevmode
  \color{red}
  test
\end{minipage}
abc &
% throws error (twice):
% Package varwidth Warning: Failed to reprocess entire contents on input line 45.
\begin{varwidth}[t]{4em}
  \leavevmode\color{red}
  test
\end{varwidth}% this is line 45
abc
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE result]

produces the following warning twice

> Package varwidth Warning: Failed to reprocess entire contents on input line 45.

As you can see, you can use `\color` within `\parbox`es and `minipage`s,
if you insert a `\leavevmode`, but it breaks the `varwidth` environment
with a warning. The behavior is similar to a `\parbox` without `\leavevmode`.

Is this (easily) fixable? Are there alternatives to `varwidth`?

To clarify what I want: I want to use colors in a `varwidth` environment
that work as intended: placement as in the line without colors.

Comment: As Henny Youngman used to say, don't do that.  You could always run the data twice (environ package), once using `\let\color=\@gobble` and varwidth and save the width, then again using parbox using the computed width.  (Actually, I think that is sort of how varwidth works.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `\textcolor`:

```
\begin{varwidth}[t]{4em}
  \textcolor{red}{test}
\end{varwidth}
```

or an additional group:

```
\begin{varwidth}[t]{4em}
  \leavevmode
  {\color{red}
  test}
\end{varwidth}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\verb|\parbox| & \verb|\minipage| & \verb|\varwidth| \\

\parbox[t]{4em}{
  test
}abc &
\begin{minipage}[t]{4em}
  test
\end{minipage}
abc &
\begin{varwidth}[t]{4em}
  test
\end{varwidth}
abc\\

\parbox[t]{4em}{
  \textcolor{red}{test}
}abc &
\begin{minipage}[t]{4em}
  \textcolor{red}{test}
\end{minipage}
abc &
\begin{varwidth}[t]{4em}
  \textcolor{red}{test}
\end{varwidth}
abc
\\
\parbox[t]{4em}{
  \leavevmode
  \color{red}
  test
}abc &
\begin{minipage}[t]{4em}
  \leavevmode
  \color{red}
  test
\end{minipage}
abc &
\begin{varwidth}[t]{4em}
  \leavevmode
  {\color{red}
  test}
\end{varwidth}
abc
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Oh, as easy as that, thanks :) would you mind explaining why this additional group does what it does?

Answer (score 1):

Starting a `minipage` or `\parbox` with `\color` always has the side effect of producing a blank line at the top. You can solve the issue by using

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{4em}
\leavevmode\color{red}% <--- don't forget
test
\end{minipage}
```

However this doesn't work for `varwidth`. You can instead start the coloring *outside* the `varwidth` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\newenvironment{colorvarwidth}[1]
 {\leavevmode\color{#1}\varwidth}
 {\endvarwidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
\verb|\parbox| & \verb|\minipage| & \verb|\varwidth| \\

%without color, everything works as expected.
\parbox[t]{4em}{
  \leavevmode\color{red}%
  test
}abc &
\begin{minipage}[t]{4em}
  \leavevmode\color{red}%
  test
\end{minipage}
abc &
\begin{colorvarwidth}{red}[t]{4em}
  test
\end{colorvarwidth}
abc
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]